# How to merge commits with same message in Git?

Tags: git

Due to some reasons, I re-combined some previously splited Git repositories. (Using git-stitch-repo) Some commits are made across several sub-projects. And after re-combined, they are shown in duplicated entries.

I want to merge these duplicated commits in sequence, like `uniq` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your commits are duplicate within the same branch, you can try a `git rebase --interactive` to [trim/squash them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302736/trimming-git-checkins-squashing-git-history) (But it is not an automatic way to remove them, like some kind of `uniq` command)

The [OP Xiè Jìléi](https://superuser.com/users/19926/xie-jilei) asks:

> Can I prepare an edit list by hand, and then send to `rebase -i`?

To which [Max Nanasy](https://superuser.com/users/127404/max-nanasy) replies:

```
GIT_EDITOR='cat "$EDIT_LIST" > ' git rebase -i "$REBASE_START"
```

Comment: Can I prepare an edit list by hand, and then send to `rebase -i`?

Comment: @谢继雷: I don't think so, but it could be the base for an interesting question of its own ;)

Comment: @XièJìléi `GIT_EDITOR='cat "$EDIT_LIST" > ' g rebase -i "$REBASE_START"` seems to work